# Why is the return false stopping the alert?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does the `return false` stop the `alert()` from working and how do I get around this? If I remove it, the alert will show up, and then it will load the page that the `<a>` tag pointed to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('static')){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                $.getJSON(href, function(data) {
                    alert('hi');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Please add newlines in your code when posting.  Otherwise its next to impossible to read your code...  Look into the <pre> button

Comment: Yah sure, I'll remember to do that next time.

Comment: @Dylan: Can it be, that the `.is('static')` is erroneous? The `is()` would test the link for having an element name 'static', which is obviously always wrong. The correct way would be `.hasClass('static')` or `.is('.static')`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Boldewyn That was just a typo. I tried taking it out altogether and nothing changed.

Comment: @Dylan: Then, have you tested the posted code snippet *alone* with a minimal markup setup? I can't find *any* reason, why it shouldn't work as expected.

Comment: I created a testcase over at http://jsbin.com/ebiwo3 and it works like it should. You should search on other places for the error.

Comment: @Boldewyn I removed all the script from my page and tried it. Same thing. I guess I'll just use $.get like stated below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that badly formed JSON is being sent to the client, which *will* prevent the callback from firing. The [manual](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) says:

> If there is a syntax error in the JSON
>   file, the request will usually fail
>   silently. Avoid frequent hand-editing
>   of JSON data for this reason.

Can you show us a snapshot of the JSON that the server is generating?

Comment: That was in fact it. Sorry for not thinking of that guys, and thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

**Answer Update!**

I have tested this thoroughly using the $.ajax functions, which is what actually gets called by $.getJSON.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if(!$(this).is('static')){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
              url: href,
              dataType: 'text',
              success: function(data) {
                  alert("hi");
              }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

With a correctly formatted JSON object, this works as expected. Here is the contents of my json.html test file:

```
{ "firstName" : "John",
                "lastName"  : "Doe",
                "age"       : 23 }
```

However, if the file contains HTML, or a badly formatted JSON object, the alert never gets called - in fact, by adding an error handler to the above example, you'll spot that it errors:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("a").click(function(event){
        if(!$(this).is('static')){
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            $.ajax({
              url: href,
              dataType: 'text',
              success: function(data) {
                  alert("hi");
              },
              error: function() {
                alert("NO!!!!");
              }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you are replacing hyperlinks in your code with this request, I'm guessing that you maybe want to use a $.get, rather than a $.getJSON. So to return to your original example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(){
            if(!$(this).is('static')){
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                $.get(href, function(data) {
                    alert('hi');
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: So how can I get around this?

Comment: Alert in the callback function

Comment: @Sohnee: What's your point? When the `alert()` is called, after the leaving of the page is cancelled (remember: that's what the `return false;` is for), it should still show up. That's the whole point of asynchronous JS.

Comment: Yep - see my revision. I'm looking at why it behaves differently between getJSON and get (which both call the underlying ajax function).

Comment: @Sohnee I tried it with just a plain $.get and your right, it did work. So whats the difference?

Comment: @Dylan - I have totally revised my answer to demonstrate why this happens, based on some tests I just ran up.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in Firefox 3 and in Chrome, with both get and getJSON.

IE8 is another story (I presume the same goes for IE7).  There, only get works; getJSON fails.  Is the JSON being returned by the server not IE-friendly?